# How can I avoid my loop to take the previous answer of the user?

Tags: java, loops

I am making a program that will take a user's input on how many numbers he wants and determine the highest number between the given. After that the user will be prompt with a Yes or no question. If the user decides to say yes, the program will loop again and if not, the program will end. Now my question is why does it take the highest number from the previous run?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IT_VILLAFLOR_Lab1_Prog2
{
   public static void main(String[] Args){
        
         int num=1,num2,Largest=0,max; 
         char YN;
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter the Max Number = ");
        max = sc.nextInt();
        
         for(num=1; num<=max; num++)
         {
             System.out.print("Enter Number " + num + ": ");             
             num2 = sc.nextInt();
             if(Largest<num2)
             {
                 Largest=num2; 
             }
             else if(num==max)
             {
                 System.out.println("The Biggest number is " + Largest );
                 System.out.print( "Do you want to try again? Y/N ");
                 YN = sc.next().charAt(0);
                 if(YN =='Y'|| YN =='y')
                 {
                     num=0;
                     System.out.print('\f');
                     System.out.print("Enter the Max Number " );
                     max = sc.nextInt();
                    }
                 else
                  {
                      System.exit(0);
                    }  
                   
                }
        
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "why does it take the highest number from the previous run?"

Comment: Where are you defining the variable 'Largest'? Why does it not get reset after the user inputs 'y' or 'Y'?

Comment: so I see what you're trying to say, just set Largest number to 0  again when user enters "Y"

Answer (score 0):

If the user wants to continue, you are resetting num to 0. Along with this, Largest also needs to be reset to 0.

```
             num=0;
             Largest=0; //new code
```

By the way, you need to change the line `else if(num==max)` to `if(num==max)` . Try the test case with max of 2 and values as 12 ,23.